# To copy number of values present in workbook1 ("A") to the work book 2 of coloumn B: VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to do like this:

Work Book1 (

Sheet1 has:

```
ColA:

AA
AA
AA
AB
AB
AB
AC
AC
AC
AC
```

Now I need to count how many are AA's, AB's, AC's and so on and represent their numbers in ColB of Work book B (Sheet1) like this:

```
ColA:     ColB:

AA     3
AB     3
AC     4
```

Here in this second work book Col A is already mentoined so need to filter or add or change Col A just to update Col (B).

With the help of users here is the code modified so far: but I need your input thank you!

Code:

```
Sub foo()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

'# Openning both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ax1jk3\Desktop\Workbooks\Book2")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ax1jk3\Desktop\Workbooks\Book1")

    'Navigate to the first WOrkBook
    Windows("Book1").Activate

    'Find all the Rown in Range A that you need to copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows.Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Navigate to the Other WOrkBook
    Windows("Book2").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'This will remove the Duplicates
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF([Book12]Sheet1!C1,RC[-1])"
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows

    Range("B1:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


'Close x:
x.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a pivot table to do this?

Comment: Yes I can do by Pivot table, but I need a macro to function by not using Pivot table-thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it, using the RemoveDuplicates function:

```
'# Opening both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ax1jk3\Desktop\Workbooks\Book2.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ax1jk3\Desktop\Workbooks\Book1.xlsx")

'Navigate to the first WorkBook
x.Sheets(1).Activate

'Copy-Paste column A to y.sheets(1)
lastRow_x = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:A" & lastRow_x).Copy

'Paste and remove duplicates
y.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates  Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo 'if your column has a header, use xlYes

'Count number of occurences of each row from y in x
lastRow_y = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For each loopCell in Range("A1:A" & lastRow_y) 'A2 if you have a header
   loopCell.Offset(0, 1) = Sheets(1).Evaluate("=COUNTIF([Book2.xlsx]Sheet1!A1:A" & lastRow_x & "," & loopCell.Address & ")")
next loopCell

'Close x:
x.Close SaveChanges:=xlNo

End Sub
```

I haven't tested it but it should be really quick!

Comment: Also, one essential thing when starting with vba (it was the very first thing I learnt), you should always avoid `.Select`

Comment: Hi Arthur, thank you for the suggestion: I have a question for example say if I wanted to paste only within the columns (A6:A24) of 'Y' I modified your's to:                            y.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("A6:A24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Range("A6:A24").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo but 
N = b1 19 to 111 happening was this action removing all other values present in 'A' and placing. But actually I need to paste and remove duplicates from and only (A6:A24) A might contain other values which I dont want to change or delete. thank you.

Comment: I suppose you can use the `RemoveDuplicates` only on `Range("A6:A24")` if you want. I understand you already have data in column A of file Y, then I suggest you use the `RemoveDuplicates` function on another temporary column (possibly in Sheets(2) for instance), to be sure you don't overwrite existing data...

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, I would avoid using the `.copy` feature.  Instead I recommend using an array to identify a unique list of items.

```vb
'# Openning both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ax1jk3\Desktop\Workbooks\Book2")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ax1jk3\Desktop\Workbooks\Book1")

'Navigate to the first WOrkBook
Windows("Book1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'identify end of source tab
source_ROW = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Do While Range("A" & source_ROW) = ""
    source_ROW = source_ROW - 1
Loop
source_ROW_end = source_ROW
source_ROW_start = 3

'initialize unique value array
Dim unique_ARRAY() As String
ReDim unique_ARRAY(1 To 1)
unique_ARRAY(1) = Range("A" & source_ROW_start)

'identify unique list
For source_ROW = source_ROW_start To source_ROW_end
    'initialize
    source_record = Range("A" & source_ROW)
    new_value = "dunno_yet"

    For i = 1 To UBound(unique_ARRAY, 1)
        If source_record = unique_ARRAY(i) Then
            'value already exists in the array
            new_value = "no"

            'no need to continue searching
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If new_value = "no" Then
        'the source_record matched values already found in the array
        'does nothing
    Else
        'a new source_record was found
        'new_value = "yes"

        'redimensionalize the array while preserving pre-existing values
        ReDim Preserve unique_ARRAY(1 To UBound(unique_ARRAY) + 1)

        'read the new value into the new upper bound of the array
        unique_ARRAY(UBound(unique_ARRAY, 1)) = source_record
    End If
Next source_ROW

'Navigate to the Other WOrkBook
Windows("Book2").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select

'cycle through each item in the array
for i = 1 to UBound(unique_ARRAY)
    'write values to book2
    Range("A" & i) = unique_ARRAY(i)
    Range("B" & i) = "=COUNTIF([Book1]Sheet1!C1,RC[-1])"
    'convert formulas to values
    Range("B" & i).Copy
    Range("B" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
next i

'Close x:
x.Close
End Sub
```

You may also consider adapting the array to count how many times a value appears.  Then you can eliminate `.PasteSpecial` at the end.